# Auto Refresh Div in Nesting ajax tabs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a project that requires nesting ajax tabs. I got an example from dynamic drive. [Dynamic Drive - Nesting Ajax Tabs](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/ajaxtabs_suppliment2.htm)

I got the tabs working fine but I would want the nested tab's content (For example "Tab3 content") from the linkprovided above to autorefresh every 5 sec to show updates. I would appreciate some help.

```
<ul id="countrytabs" class="shadetabs">
   <li><a href="external1.htm" rel="countrycontainer" class="selected">Tab1</a></li>
   <li><a href="external2.htm" rel="countrycontainer">Tab2</a></li>
   <li><a href="externalnested.htm" rel="countrycontainer">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>

// Main Tab content is displayed here (External tabs are displayed here too)
<div id="countrydivcontainer"> </div>



**Here is "externalnested.htm"**

 <ul id="provincetabs" class="shadetabs">
    <li><a href="external1.htm" rel="provincedivcontainer">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="external2.htm" rel="provincedivcontainer">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="external3.htm" rel="provincedivcontainer">Tab 3</a></li>
 </ul>

 // External Tab content is displayed here
 <div id="provincedivcontainer"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
 var countries=new ddajaxtabs("countrytabs", "countrydivcontainer")
 countries.setpersist(true)
 countries.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
 countries.init()

 countries.onajaxpageload=function(pageurl){
 if (pageurl.indexOf("externalnested.htm")!=-1){
 provinces=new ddajaxtabs("provincetabs", "provincedivcontainer")
 provinces.setpersist(true)
 provinces.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
 provinces.init()
    }


 if (pageurl.indexOf("externalnested.htm")!=-1){
 var seconds = 5000; // time in milliseconds
 var reload = function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'nested-tab-1.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#countrydivcontainer').html(data);
          setTimeout(function() {
             reload();
          }, seconds);
      }
   });
 };
 reload();
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't see any question here? your code seems to do what you are trying to accomplish. if you failed, describe how.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut  It doesn't seem to refresh on my localhost. I use xampp

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pageurl.indexOf("externalnested.htm")!=-1){
var seconds = 5000; // time in milliseconds
var reload = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'nested-tab-1.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#countrydivcontainer').html(data);
      }
    });
};
var timer=setInterval("reload()", seconds);
```